# How to minimize number of bytes writen to disk by sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, io, raspberry-pi

I use sqlite on Raspberry Pi to store sensor readings. The table structure is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensors(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, codename TEXT, name TEXT)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensorvalues(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sensorid INTEGER, value DECIMAL(10,2), time DATETIME, FOREIGN KEY(sensorid) REFERENCES sensors(id))
```

Each time I insert record to 'sensorvalues' table (about 20 bytes of data) iotop shows that about 30Kb is written do disk.
In  order to protect sd card from corruption I would like to minimize data written to permanent memory. I know that writing exactly 20 bytes is not possible because IO operations use page structures and buffers, but writing 30Kb on each commit seems too much. 
Is there any way to tune sqlite to minimize ammount of written data to neccessary minimum?

Comment: @duffymo, My first approach was to use MySql, but it written like 200Kb each commit, so I migrarted to sqlite which is more suitable here I think. I know that writing exactly to binary file would be even better, but I'd like to avoid parsing it manually.

Comment: IO includes the rollback journal or WAL, and possibly a checkpoint. [Source](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html), but note that it's a draft document. I don't know how much disk *those* writes might take.

Comment: SQLite takes care to get Durability of transactions right; that requires more iops to achieve than a straight write, but it also means that when the transaction completes, the data is _definitely_ there.

Comment: Try a NoSQL document alternative if you can do without ACID and it still meets your needs.  It's always a trade off.  Be sure you aren't guilty of premature optimization.  Even 20KB doesn't sound like a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting into these tables requires updating both the table and the index, and for reliability in the case of a crash, the database first writes the old data to a rollback journal, then updates the database file itself, then deletes the rollback journal.

You could disable the safety features with [PRAGMA journal_mode = memory](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) and/or [PRAGMA synchronous = off](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous), but

> if the application using SQLite crashes in the middle of a transaction when the MEMORY journaling mode is set, then the database file will very likely go corrupt.

For many inserts, [WAL mode](http://sqlite.org/wal.html) is likely to be more efficient.